# Google Maps API v3: How do I dynamically change the marker icon?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps API v3, how do I programmatically change the marker icon?

What I would like to do is, when someone hovers over a link - to have the corresponding marker icon on the map change colors to denote the marker in question.

Essentially, the same function as what Roost does.

When you hover over a home listing on the left, the corresponding marker on the right changes color

Comment: Your live example has gone down. Just wanted to let you know. I assume it is similar to what happens at airbnb.com?

Answer (score 190):

Call the `marker.setIcon('newImage.png')`... Look [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#Marker) for the docs.

Are you asking about the actual way to do it? You could just create each `div`, and a add a `mouseover` and `mouseout` listener that would change the icon and back for the markers.

Comment: that helped me figure out how to change the animation of a marker: `markersArray[0].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);`

Answer (score 22):

You can also use a circle as a marker icon, for example:

```
var oMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    sName: "Marker Name",
    map: map,
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 8.5,
        fillColor: "#F00",
        fillOpacity: 0.4,
        strokeWeight: 0.4
    },
});
```

and then, if you want to change the marker dynamically (like on mouseover), you can, for example:

```
oMarker.setIcon({
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 10,
            fillColor: "#00F",
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 1
        })
```

Answer (score 8):

This thread might be dead, but [StyledMarker](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/) is available for API v3. Just bind the color change you want to the correct DOM event using the **addDomListener()** method. This [example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/examples/change_color.htm) is pretty close to what you want to do. If you look at the page source, change:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("changeButton"),"click",function() {
  styleIcon.set("color","#00ff00");
  styleIcon.set("text","Go");
});
```

to something like:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener("mouseover",function() {
  styleIcon.set("color","#00ff00");
  styleIcon.set("text","Go");
});
```

That should be enough to get you moving along.

The Wikipedia page on [DOM Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events) will also help you target the event that you want to capture on the client-side.

Good luck (if you still need it)

Comment: Yes, but changing the maps pointer is done by changing the cursor property in CSS, not in the Maps API - see the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor)

Comment: This [StackOverflow question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652178) may further guide you.

Answer (score 5):

The [GMaps Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/) has a plugin called [MapIconMaker](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/mapiconmaker/) that makes it easy to generate different marker styles on the fly.  It uses Google Charts to draw the markers.

There's a good demo [here](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/mapiconmaker/1.1/examples/markericonoptions-wizard.html) that shows what kind of markers you can make with it.

Comment: MapIconMaker is not available for maps API v3

Comment: [StyledMarker](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/) for API v3 is though. HTH.

Comment: Unfortunately Google Charts API has recently been officially deprecated by Google :(

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code

```
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>

<script>

    function initialize()
    {
        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: 10,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP    
                         };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), mapOptions);
        var markers = [
            ['title-1', '<img style="width:100%;" src="canberra_hero_image.jpg"></img>', 51.508742, -0.120850, '<p> Hello - 1 </p>'],
            ['title-2', '<img style="width:100%;" src="canberra_hero_image.jpg"></img>', 51.508742, -0.420850, '<p> Hello - 2 </p>'],
            ['title-3', '<img style="width:100%;" src="canberra_hero_image.jpg"></img>', 51.508742, -0.720850, '<p> Hello - 3 </p>'],
            ['title-4', '<img style="width:100%;" src="canberra_hero_image.jpg"></img>', 51.508742, -1.020850, '<p> Hello - 4 </p>'],
            ['title-5', '<img style="width:100%;" src="canberra_hero_image.jpg"></img>', 51.508742, -1.320850, '<p> Hello - 5 </p>']
        ];

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
        var testMarker = [];
        var status = [];
        for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) 
        {
            var title = markers[i][0];
            var loan = markers[i][1];
            var lat = markers[i][2];
            var long = markers[i][3];
            var add = markers[i][4];


            var iconGreen = 'img/greenMarker.png'; //green marker
            var iconRed = 'img/redMarker.png';     //red marker

            var infoWindowContent = loan + "\n" + placeId + add;

            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
            bounds.extend(position);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                title: title,
                position: position,
                icon: iconGreen
            });
            testMarker[i] = marker;
            status[i] = 1;
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', ( function toggleBounce( i,status,testMarker) 
            {
                return function() 
                {
                    infoWindow.setContent(markers[i][1]+markers[i][4]);
                    if( status[i] === 1 )
                    {
                        testMarker[i].setIcon(iconRed);
                        status[i] = 0;

                    }
                    for( var k = 0; k <  markers.length ; k++ )
                    {
                        if(k != i)
                        {
                            testMarker[k].setIcon(iconGreen);
                            status[i] = 1;

                        }
                    }
                    infoWindow.open(map, testMarker[i]);
                }
            })( i,status,testMarker));
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event)
        {
            this.setZoom(8);
            google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

<div id="mapDiv" style="width:820px; height:300px"></div>
```