# Google Maps Infowindow Auto Updating

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, auto-update, infowindow

I have an app in which I need the data in the `infowindow` bubbles to update automatically. I've checked around and I see methods for moving markers, updating marker colors, and the like, but nothing with directly updating infowindow content. I am pulling the value necessary (e.g. `building[i][7]` ) from a hidden DOM element whose content automatically updates, and I need the infowindow's content to automatically update alongside it.

Here is the code I am using to draw the `infowindow` bubbles.

```
infowindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
for (i=0;i<buildings.length;i++){
    marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position:new google.maps.LatLng(buildings[i][4],buildings[i][5]),
        map:map,
        shadow:shadow,
        icon:greenIcon,
        title:buildings[i][0]+" \n"+buildings[i][1],
        zIndex:buildings[i][6]
    });
}
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',(function(marker,i){
    return function(){
        infowindow.setContent(
            '<h2>'+buildings[i][0]+'</h2>'+
            '<p>'+buildings[i][2]+'</p>'+
            '<p>'+buildings[i][7]+'</p>'
        );infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }
})(marker,i));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there some kind of event that will fire to let you know the data has changed? Do you mean that you want the InfoWindow content to change whenever the hidden DOM element's data changes?

Comment: No event fires other than the hidden div's content changing (is there some way of measuring that as an event?).

You are correct that I want the InfoWindow content to change whenever the hidden div's content changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way in JavaScript to be notified when the content of a `DIV` changes, but I believe the [jQuery.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function or the newer (jQuery v1.7) [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function provide a way to implement what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. I've recently learned about `.delegate()`, `.live()`, and `.on()`, and while I'm sure I could have made them work somehow, I've decided to go with a different solution, which is updating the value for only the selected infowindow, and only when it's clicked. This solves a number of problems.

I appreciate the answer. Cheers.

Comment: How you update infowindow? can update your solution in your answer?Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

on funciton call just run

```
    infowindow.setContent(
        '<h2>'+buildings[i][0]+'</h2>'+
        '<p>'+buildings[i][2]+'</p>'+
        '<p>'+buildings[i][7]+'</p>'
    );infowindow.open(map,marker);
```