# Display infowindow by default and different markers in Google Maps

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

My HTML:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 625px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

My JQuery:

```
var infowindow = null;
    $(document).ready(function () { initialize();  });

    function initialize() {

        var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(40.68194, -73.94439);

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: centerMap,
            scaleControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        setMarkers(map, sites);
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "loading...", maxWidth: 150
            });

        //var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
        //bikeLayer.setMap(map);
    }   

    function setMarkers(map, markers) {

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var sites = markers[i];
            var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: siteLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: sites[0],
                zIndex: sites[3],
                html: sites[4]
            });

            var contentString = "Some content";

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                //alert(this.html);
                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve,

1. To show site[0] infobubble on page load by default.
2. To have different marker for each on the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To show site[0] infobubble on page load by default.**

```
infowindow.open(map, site[0]);
```

**To have different marker for each on the map.**
Assuming you mean different markers images, you could either set them while creating markers or simply
call `site[i].setIcon('newImage.png')`, later

ref:[Google Maps API v3: How do I dynamically change the marker icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941260/google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-dynamically-change-the-marker-icon)

Answer (score 1):

1. to use custom icons, for a simple icon, just add an icon URL to your sites array, use it in your marker definition.

   ```
           icon: sites[5]
   ```
2. keep references to the markers:

   ```
   // in the global scope
   var gmarkers = [];



   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       var sites = markers[i];
       var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: siteLatLng,
           map: map,
           title: sites[0],
           zIndex: sites[3],
           html: sites[4],
           icon: sites[5]
       });
       gmarkers.push(marker);
       var contentString = "Some content";

       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
           //alert(this.html);
           infowindow.setContent(this.html);
           infowindow.open(map, this);
       });
   ```
3. Then to click on the 1st marker (which will open the infowindow):

   google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[0], "click");

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_changeIcons.html)