# Change of Google map marker icon with different places

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have two locations.I want to change marker icon for both the location with an external image. But in the current code both places takes the same image. Any help please?

```
    var markers = [
     ['Sydney', lat,long],
     ['New York', lat,long],


    function initializeMaps() {
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false
};
var image = 'img/logos.png';
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  


    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
        map: map,
    icon: image
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Colour the first marker of a Google Map a different colour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900210/colour-the-first-marker-of-a-google-map-a-different-colour)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it. But thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have defined only 1 image,

add for each loc the image to the array and then access it using markers[i][3] if you put it at the end.

This should work:

```
var markers = [
     ['Sydney', lat,long, 'url-to-image'],
     ['New York', lat,long, 'url-to-image'],


    function initializeMaps() {
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false
};
//var image = 'img/logos.png';
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  


    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
        map: map,
    icon: markers[i][3]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
}
```