# Set different icons within long list of Google Map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I have a map where a large number of markers (100) drop on a custom google map. Currently the icon is set before running through loop of lat/long.

Based on the code below, is there a way to specify a different icon for a few specific locations be a different icon?

Thanks in advance

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
     var mapcenter = new google.maps.LatLng(###, ###);
     var icon = { 
    url: 'URL-OF-ICON'
};
       var houses = [
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), 
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###), <!-- I want these last two to be a different icon -->
new google.maps.LatLng( ###, ###)  <!-- I want these last two to be a different icon -->

      ];

      var markers = [];
      var iterator = 0;

      var map;


      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 11,
        center: mapcenter,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       zoomControl: true,
       zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },
       panControl: false
        };


        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                mapOptions);

        } 

 for (var i = 0; i < houses.length; i++) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            addMarker();
          }, i * 50);
        }

      function addMarker() {
 markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          icon: icon,
          position: houses[iterator],
          map: map,
          draggable: false,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        }));
        iterator++;
      }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)


    </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Colour the first marker of a Google Map a different colour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900210/colour-the-first-marker-of-a-google-map-a-different-colour)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display infowindow by default and different markers in Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844370/display-infowindow-by-default-and-different-markers-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 1):

Make each map marker it's own object

```
  var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    icon: url: 'images/beachball.png',
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });

var markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    icon: url: 'images/beachflag.png',
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
```

Comment: Thanks would you say this is the best/only way? Reason is there are nearly 100 markers.

Comment: Performance wise, no. Unfortunately, this is the way that the API is set up. To add markers, instead of adding them using just their LatLang property, you are just defining the properties of each Marker object before you add it. LatLang is simply a property of the built in Marker object.

Mapmarker( some lat lang, url: 'images/beachball.png', yourmapid, yourtitle)
    function Mapmarker(myLatLng, aicon, amap, atitle){
        new google.maps.Marker({ 
        this.position = myLatLng,
        this.icon = aicon,
        this.map = amap,
        this.title = atitle
  });

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain, much appreciated.