# Custom marker with rounded image inside in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is there a way how to set custom place marker with rounded image in it in Google maps? I've found this map and that's what I would like implement http://themestarz.net/html/locations/index-map-version-3.html.

I've gone through these documentations, but none of them allowed what exactly I would like to have https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-modern.

EDIT to clarify: I would like to use same marker (drop) for all places and dynamically place the rounded image into them, image would be different for each place. Rounded image in drop should serve as a very small thumbnail of place.

Comment: Surely https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons or https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#symbols covers this?

Comment: Maybe this will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941260/google-maps-api-v3-how-do-i-dynamically-change-the-marker-icon?rq=2

Comment: I went through those documentations already, but I need a little bit diffrent thing. I've updated my question, sorry for not to specify enough.